# Radio button and popup Site accessibility checker

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, radio-button

I am creating a project using angular and material.

I am using the `mat-radio-button` and using Site accessibility checker tool from chrome extension but it show me error on radio button.

```
<mat-radio-group formControlName="csff" class="conflict-radio">
    <mat-radio-button  class="ml-0 conflict-radio" value="old">{{ emailAddress }}</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button  class="ml-0 conflict-radio" value="new"> Email </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Error:

Container Element is empty role="radiogroup".

[image]

Comment: What is your component selector for radio group?

Answer (score 0):

A group of radio buttons. May contain one or more  elements.

Selector: `mat-radio-group`

Exported as: `matRadioGroup`

Event emitted when the group value changes. Change events are only emitted when the value changes due to user interaction with a radio button (the same behavior as <input type-"radio">).

[API reference](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/api) for Angular Material radio

```
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct execept from below line

```
<mat-radio-button  class="ml-0 conflict-radio" value="old">{{.emailAddress}}</mat-radio-button>
```

So i think you are getting error because of this {{.emailAddress}}

you should try with simple text and check its work fine or not.